# How to "Whitelist the return URL"?

Tags: url, paypal, return, whitelist

In PayPal URL onboarding document, it says:

"Whitelist the return URL
To return the merchant to your site, ask your PayPal account manager to whitelist the URL. If you do not whitelist this URL, the merchant is redirected to the account setup page."

How exactly do you do this?  I've been looking everywhere and there is nowhere to be found how exactly to do this???

Comment: From this PayPal document: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplaces/connected/url/#whitelist-the-return-url